# How to make relation between tables which are in same dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have one dataset in which there are
40 tables. Now I want to make a relation
between these tables and show
important data in grid. How do i do this?

Comment: Ashish, you've asked a very specific and answerable question ("how to relate tables in a dataset").  You'll get better results here if you remove the second, much broader and more vague question ("how to show this related data in a grid").

Answer (score 5):

If you're creating a typed dataset, it's easiest to create the relations in Visual Studio's dataset designer.  Just right-click on the table in the designer, select Add->Relation, and specify the relation.

If you need to specify the relation in code, you can do it like this:

```
dataSet.Relations.Add(dataSet.Tables["Customers"].Columns["customerId"],
    dataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["customerId"]);
```

Read all about it in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.childrelations.aspx).

Comment: But i fetched all tables from webservice and bind it in dataset. Now i wanna make a relationship between these tables and show some important data in a grid. Please help me out.

Comment: My answer describes exactly how do do that.

Answer (score 1):

That is a large number of `DataTables` to have in a `DataSet`.

The first thing I would consider would be to reduce the number of `DataTables` (and eliminate the need for `Relations`) by populating the `DataTables` with queries that JOIN the database tables. For example, instead of having one `DataTable` for Product Category and another for Product Detail, it might be possible to combine the data for both database tables into one `DataTable`. Similarly, for Customer, Customer Address and Customer Phone, retrieve all of the data in one DataTable by using one query that does a JOIN on all three database tables.

Once you have minimized the number of `DataTables` in the `DataSet`, you can add `Relations` between `DataTables` if they have matching columns (even if the columns have different names). For example, there might be an Orders `DataTable` with a CustomerID column that matches the ID column in the Customers `DataTable`.

Here is the code to add a `Relation` to the `DataSet` for that situation. Assume that we have a `DataSet` dst containing two `DataTables` Customers and Orders.

```
DataColumn customerColumn, orderColumn;
customerColumn = dst.Tables["Customers"].Columns["ID"];
orderColumn = dst.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"];
DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("CustomerOrders", customerColumn, orderColumn);
dst.Relations.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds.Relations.Add("Products_Category",
    ds.Tables("Categories").Columns("CategoryID"),
    ds.Tables("Products").Columns("CategoryID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
ds.Relations.Add("Products_Category",
    ds.Tables("Categories").Columns("CategoryID"),
    ds.Tables("Products").Columns("CategoryID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateRelation() 
   {
       // Get the DataColumn objects from two DataTable objects 
       // in a DataSet. Code to get the DataSet not shown here.
       DataColumn parentColumn = 
       DataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustID"];
       DataColumn childColumn = 
       DataSet1.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustID"];
       // Create DataRelation.
       DataRelation relCustOrder;
       relCustOrder = new DataRelation("CustomersOrders", 
       parentColumn, childColumn);
       // Add the relation to the DataSet.
       DataSet1.Relations.Add(relCustOrder);
    }
```