# c# devexpress xtrareport add field name into field list by programmatically on existing report

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, report, xtrareport

i try to custom on existing report to add some field name from Table ASMBTL (for example) into field list on existing report which have create and compile.
I know have to create an relation, i try different approach still fail due to i still new to C# and devexpress programming.

The Attachment of the image is what i try to learn and success by using C# coding and can extract any value from any table which not include inside the filed list of any original report. I try to learn this way so i would able to custom any existing report just using c# script anytime at anyplace.

Below is some code i learn from web and manage to add the tab "Assembly Custome Add On Table" inside the field list, but is not success to put it in under "Stock Assembly Master". I still can't understand how to add relation to proceed like the photo attachment result.

```
DataTable dtMyTable = GetCustomTableData(); 
dtMyTable.TableName = "Assembly Custome Add On Table";    
AddCustomTable(ds, dtMyTable);                              

private void AddCustomTable(DataSet ds, DataTable dt) {
  if (ds.Tables.Contains(dt.TableName) == false)
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);                        }

private DataTable GetCustomTableData()
{Return __report.DBSetting.GetDataTable("Select DtlKey, DocKey, OrderQty" from ASMDTL", false);
```

[This is what I try to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD7gY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem base on [How to make relation between tables which are in same dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992782/how-to-make-relation-between-tables-which-are-in-same-dataset) link had shown me the way to solution.